# fetch all data from table using doctrine in codeigniter

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I had integrated doctrine 2 in codeigniter 2. i had the database which i convert into entity in store in models/Entity

my controller goes like this ..

```
  public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
        $this->load->model('doctrine_model');   
    }
    public function index()

    {
        $this->doctrine_model->get_object();


                        }
```

}

and model goes like this....

```
    Class Doctrine_model extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library('doctrine');
        //$accountTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('ss_class');
         $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
    }


    function get_object()
    {
       $records = $this->em->getRepository("Entity\SsClass")->findAll();
    }
}
```

when i run this code i get this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SsClass in D:\xampp\htdocs\new_doctrine\application\models\Entity\SsClass.php on line 14
```

As i had already loaded the doctrine library in autoload  but cannot figure out what is going on here...

Comment: i think no one will reply .. (:

Comment: just add use namespace Entity in the generated entity class and the problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

getRepository method load your entity automatically so probably your entity class is autoload in other place such as config.php or require function.